# Phonegap - HTML/JS to Container Communication

Tags: android, cordova

I'm reading about Phonegap JS API despite the fancy stuff, I like to understand some basics of how the container & javascript communicate with other? currently it says some native bridge is written to do it, but not very clear what is that bridge, Can anyone shed some light on communication protocol between JS/Container works? or any link/video/blogs will be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find this useful link: [Dissecting PhoneGap's Architecture](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/09/dissecting-phonegaps-architecture/). Of course, if that doesn't give you the level of detail you want, you can always check out [Android's Exec function](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/assets/www/cordova.js#L839)